# CRTP and template template parameters limitation

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, crtp

I'm trying to experiment with CRTP but I am puzzled on why the following code does not compile.

```
template<template<class...> class CBase>
struct ComponentX : public CBase<ComponentX>
  {
  // This does NOT compile
  };

template<template<class...> class CBase>
struct ComponentY : public CBase<int>
  {
  // This does compile
  };
```

Do you know if there is some limitation for template template parameters in the case of CRTP?

Comment: Nice question. Though, everything before `ComponentX`'s definition is irrelevant to the MCVE.

Comment: Thanks, yes you're totally right. It was just to give an example of how to use it (I forgot to write the last part though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A class template name stands for the "current specialization" (i.e. it is an injected class name) only after the opening `{` of the class template definition, inside its scope. Before that, it's a template name.

So `CBase<ComponentX>` is an attempt to pass a template as an argument to `CBase`, which expects a pack of types.

The fix is fairly simple:

```
template<template<class...> class CBase>
struct ComponentX : public CBase<ComponentX<CBase>> // Specify the arguments
  {
  // This should compile now
  };
```

`ComponentX<CBase>` is the name of the specialization you wish to provide as a type argument.

Comment: Thank you, it totally makes sense